# How to return View for editing its property?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm making a class that returns its editor view.
But got an error

> Cannot convert value of type 'Published.Publisher' to expected
> argument type 'Binding'

This is simple test code for Playgrounds.

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport


struct EditorView: View {
    @Binding var text: String

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Name:")
            TextField("Jerry", text: $text)
        }
    }
}

class MyModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var name: String = "Tom"

    func editorView() -> some View {
        EditorView(text: $name) // [ERROR] Cannot convert value of type 'Published.Publisher' to expected argument type 'Binding<String>'
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model: MyModel = .init()

    var body: some View {
        model.editorView()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Preview: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 375, height: 400))
    }
}

let viewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = nav
```

What is wrong?

---

2022.03.23 Added

I tested to make a view without binding, it works. I think that the class can create a view with its property. But can't pass the @Binding.

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport


struct EditorView: View {
    @Binding var text: String

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Name:")
            TextField("Jerry", text: $text)
        }
    }
}

// Just display the name parameter
struct DispView: View {
    let name: String
    var body: some View {
        Text(name)
    }
}

class MyModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var name: String = "Tom"

    @ViewBuilder
    func editorView() -> some View {
//      EditorView(text: $name) // Error at this line.
        DispView(name: name) // Pass the property.
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model: MyModel = .init()

    var body: some View {
        model.editorView()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Preview: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 375, height: 400))
    }
}

let viewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = nav
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create EditorView in wrong place, put it in your `ContentView` instead of your ViewModel. ViewModel is for holding data (or model) instead of View. I believe SwiftUI is not designed for carrying view along.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model: MyModel = .init()

    var body: some View {
        editorView
    }
}

extension ContentView {
    @ViewBuilder
    var editorView: some View {
        EditorView(text: $model.name)
    }
}
```

If you still want to put it in your ViewModel, this should be the working code. You can create new Binding as parameter for your view initializer.

```
@ViewBuilder
func editorView() -> some View {
    EditorView(text: 
        Binding { name } set: { newName in self.name = newName }
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
This is what I want to know.
But this may not good solution.
I change the design to not use editorView() function.

Answer (score 0):

Binding is provided by `StateObject` wrapper (on `ObservableObject`), and a view should be created in `body` (ie. in view hierarchy), so it should look like

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model: MyModel = .init()

    var body: some View {
        EditorView(text: model.$name)     // << here !!
    }
}
```

*Note:* alternate would be to make `EditorView` dependent to `MyModel` directly and then inside such view you could create a wrapper which would provide needed binding.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

I want to make some sub-class of MyModel and override the editorView().
But you wrote 'a view should be create in body', it means it's impossible to do what I want...

I want

```
func editorView() -> some View {
 VStack {
  super.editorView()
  
  MyEditView()
 }
}
```

Is it possible like that?

Comment: No, you will get error from compiler, because that would be different type of view (`some View` is not a type it is only a mark for compiler that it detects itself which type is returned, but one function is not allowed to return different types).

Comment: Give up! Beyond understanding my English and programming skill. Thank you very much!

Comment: I can make a view with property. (I edited the question)
I hope that I can pass the binding value.